# Catch RuntimeException thrown in a lambda and rethrow it as checked

Tags: java, exception, lambda, java-8

I am trying to figure out why my code is throwing a `IllegalStateException`, and not my custom one, which I hoped it to throw.

```
public final class CollectorUtils {
    private CollectorUtils() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static <E, R, X extends Throwable> Collector<E, ?, R> listAndThenCollector(final Predicate<List<E>> listPredicate, final Function<List<E>, R> listFunction, final Function<Throwable, X> exceptionWrapper) throws X {
        Objects.requireNonNull(listPredicate);
        Objects.requireNonNull(listFunction);
        Objects.requireNonNull(exceptionWrapper);
        try {
            return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> {
                if (!listPredicate.test(list)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(); //Line that throws the exception
                }
                return listFunction.apply(list);
            });
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            throw exceptionWrapper.apply(ex);
        }
    }

    public static <E> Collector<E, ?, E> singleElementCollector() throws NotASingleElementException {
        return listAndThenCollector(list -> list.size() == 1, list -> list.get(0), NotASingleElementException::new);
    }
}
```

The `IllegalStateException` gets thrown at the line: `throw new IllegalStateException()`.

Example usage:

```
public static void test() {
    try {
        Integer result = IntStream.range(0, 2)
                .boxed()
                .collect(CollectorUtils.singleElementCollector());
    } catch (NotASingleElementException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CollectorUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

This code should throw a `NotASingleElementException`, instead it throws an `IllegalStateException`, how could I get it to work?

A stracktrace of the wrong behaviour when doing an actual job:

```
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at dpc2.base.utils.CollectorUtils.lambda$listAndThenCollector$0(CollectorUtils.java:28)
    at dpc2.base.utils.CollectorUtils$$Lambda$21/2071035411.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$6(Function.java:88)
    at java.util.function.Function$$Lambda$22/63121782.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:503)
    at dpc2.base.utils.ImageMagickUtils.convertPDFToTIFF(ImageMagickUtils.java:30)
    at dpc2.server.convert.ConvertConsumer.accept(ConvertConsumer.java:20)
    at dpc2.server.convert.ConvertConsumer.accept(ConvertConsumer.java:14)
    at dpc2.base.checker.BaseChecker.lambda$null$0(BaseChecker.java:116)
    at dpc2.base.checker.BaseChecker$$Lambda$15/2121862243.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Which line in that source block is `CollectorUtils.java:28`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That is the `throw new IllegalStateException()`.

Comment: @ skiwi: You should update the question to say that's the line. (And be really sure it is, sometimes we assume things but if we actually check, we realize we've mislead ourselves.)

Comment: Fixed an important typo: It should be `list -> list.size() == 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your collector is returned but not collected in the `listAndThenCollector` method. The actual collection happens with:

```
.collect(CollectorUtils.singleElementCollector());
```

which is in your test method. That's when the exception is thrown.

Comment: And at that point the `IllegalStateException` has already been thrown, so it's too late to recover from it. I might need to go with custom unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's because when you call `Collectors.collectingAndThen` you pass it a lambda which does not execute at that time. When it ultimately executes your catch is no longer there to catch it.

Couldn't you use:

```
//throw new IllegalStateException();
throw exceptionWrapper.apply(new IllegalStateException());
```